# Detecting zerofill in MySQL field with VS 2008 VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, zerofill

Using .NET connector: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref.html

A field is set in MySQL as:

```
decimal(6) zerofill not null
```

How can the "zerofill" flag be detected in VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain column information using `SHOW COLUMNS IN tablename`, this query returns something in the form:

```
field         type                          null   key   default    extra
fieldname     int(10) unsigned zerofill      no            0
```

So to obtain the flag zerofill you have to look in type if the string returned in int contains the 'zerofill' string:

Something like this will do the trick:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dim conn as MySqlConnection
    conn = new MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server = yourserver; Database = yourdb; Uid = youruser;Pwd = yourpassword;"

    conn.Open

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SHOW COLUMNS IN yourtable"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    dim reader as MySqlDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    while reader.Read
        Console.WriteLine("Field:{0}, zerofill:{1}",reader("field"),if(reader("type").ToString().Contains("zerofill"),true,false))
    end while
    conn.Close()
}
```